# A simple client-server - Android<>PC

Tags: android, android-activity, client

I am testing socket programming on Android however I am having a problem. The client is basically launched through the main activity with a basic function of sending a message to the server and getting a reply.

the client activity:

```
package com.test.socket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class socketActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String input;
private EditText et;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
private TextView tv;
private String message;
private ObjectInputStream ois;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try{

        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(),7777);
        //send to server

        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //read from server
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


        //System.out.println("Message from Server: "+message);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }

    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button:
        input = et.getText().toString();
        try {
            oos.writeObject(input);
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            message = (String) ois.readObject();
            tv.setText("Message from Server: "+message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
}



}
```

The Server class launched separately from JCreator listening to port 7777:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;

public class server {

private ServerSocket server;
private int port = 7777;

public server()
{
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    server example = new server();
    example.handleConnection();
}

public void handleConnection()
{
    System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");

    while(true)
    {
        try{
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            new ConnectionHandler(socket);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

ConnectionHandler class which the Server accesses:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

private Socket socket;

public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket)
{
    this.socket = socket;

    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{

        //receive from client
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String message = (String) ois.readObject();

        System.out.println("Message from client: "+message);

        if(message.equals("check"))
        {
            System.out.println("Checking for malicious interference...");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Status: Files are good.");
        }

        //send response to client
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


        if(message.equals("check"))
        {
            oos.writeObject("Checking...");
        }

        else oos.writeObject("Invalid input");



        ois.close();
        oos.close();
        socket.close();

        System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I have tested the code on JCreator and Eclipse through Java application not Android app and it worked perfect. However when I try doing it through the activity, it's not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, localhost would point to the phone/emulator itself. It doesn't point to your server. The following line below is pointing to your Android device/emulator and not your server. You need to get the actual IP of the server to get it working from your Android

```
    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(),7777);
```

It works through Java App, because when you execute it from the context of Java Application, the localhost is pointing to the same server location.

Comment: I tried it. The emulator is not showing the layout anymore, it freezes and logcat states:

request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: What did you put as an address?

Comment: my computer's IP address which I got from Ipconfig. that's the one I need to use right?

Comment: that's probably because you are using ObjectOutputStream. Is there any particular reason why you are wrapping the String like that? Also, the way you code it right now will block the UI Thread. You should consider listening on separate Thread and performing action on UI thread as the input comes from the server